# Why is my Java SE application doing cyclic entries on jdbc inserts

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a Java SE application that uses PostgreSQL as the back-end. It uses JDBC for connecting to the PostgreSQL server. Occasionally users experience some anomalies that are quite strange. One insert may repeat many times instead of just one insert as intended. This ends up impacting on data integrity. This happens on more than one form though the anomaly is rare. What could be wrong and how can this be prevented? I use PostgreSQL 9.2 and later versions.

Charles

this is my code:

```
    java.util.Date periodFrom = null;
    java.util.Date periodTo = null;

    try {

        java.sql.Statement stmtf = connectDB.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet rsetf = stmtf.executeQuery("SELECT period_from,period_to FROM period_setup WHERE period_status ilike 'Open'");
        while (rsetf.next()) {
            periodFrom = rsetf.getDate(1);
            periodTo = rsetf.getDate(2);
        }

    } catch (java.sql.SQLException sq) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, sq.getMessage(), "Error Message!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println(sq.getMessage());

    }

    if (datePicker1.getDate().before(periodFrom) || datePicker1.getDate().after(periodTo)) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cannot save before or after the accounting period set \n Contact head of accounts".toUpperCase(), "Caution Message", javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } else {
        if (jTable1.isEditing()) {
            jTable1.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
        }
        double actual = 0.00;
        double comp = 0.00;
        double total = 0.00;
        double price = 0.00;
        String units = null;
        java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

        long dateNow = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        java.sql.Date datenowSql = new java.sql.Date(dateNow);
        String user = null;
        try {
            try {

                connectDB.setAutoCommit(false);
                java.sql.Statement pst2 = connectDB.createStatement();
                java.sql.ResultSet rs = pst2.executeQuery("select current_user");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    user = rs.getObject(1).toString();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {

                    if (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2) == null || jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    //java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = connectDB.prepareStatement("update st_stock_item set quantity_instock = quantity_instock + '"+jTable1.getValueAt(i,2).toString()+"' where department = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' and description = '"+jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).toString()+"'");

                    } else {

                        double quantity = Double.parseDouble(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                        double expired = Double.parseDouble(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
                        double damaged = Double.parseDouble(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, 4).toString());

                        actual = quantity + expired + damaged;

                        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
                            java.sql.Statement pstmt6 = connectDB.createStatement();
                            java.sql.ResultSet rs6 = pstmt6.executeQuery("select product_id,balance,transfer_price from st_stock_prices where product ilike '" + jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0) + "' and department ilike '" + jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'");
                            while (rs6.next()) {
                                units = rs6.getObject(1).toString();
                                comp = rs6.getDouble(2);
                                price = rs6.getDouble(3);
                            }
                        } else {
                            java.sql.Statement pstmt6 = connectDB.createStatement();
                            java.sql.ResultSet rs6 = pstmt6.executeQuery("select item_code,quantity_instock,buying_price from st_stock_item where description ilike '" + jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0) + "'");
                            while (rs6.next()) {
                                units = rs6.getObject(1).toString();
                                comp = rs6.getDouble(2);
                                price = rs6.getDouble(3);

                            }
                        }
                        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = connectDB.prepareStatement("insert into st_stock_count values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)");
                        pstmt.setObject(1, jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0));
                        pstmt.setObject(2, units);
                        pstmt.setDouble(3, 0.00);
                        pstmt.setString(8, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        pstmt.setDouble(4, java.lang.Double.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString()));
                        pstmt.setDouble(5, java.lang.Double.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString()));
                        pstmt.setDouble(6, java.lang.Double.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 4).toString()));
                        pstmt.setDouble(7, 0.00);
                        pstmt.setString(9, user);
                        pstmt.setDouble(10, 0.00);
                        pstmt.setTime(11, new java.sql.Time(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
                        pstmt.setTime(12, new java.sql.Time(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
                        pstmt.setDouble(13, quantity * price);
                        pstmt.setDouble(14, price);
                        pstmt.setObject(15, jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1));
                        pstmt.setDate(16, com.afrisoftech.lib.SQLDateFormat.getSQLDate(datePicker1.getDate()));
                        pstmt.executeUpdate();

                        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt11 = connectDB.prepareStatement("insert into st_sub_stores values(? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)");
                        pstmt11.setString(1, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        pstmt11.setObject(2, jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0));
                        pstmt11.setDouble(3, java.lang.Double.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString()));
                        pstmt11.setDouble(4, 0.00);
                        pstmt11.setDouble(5, price);
                        pstmt11.setDouble(6, quantity * price);
                        pstmt11.setDouble(7, 0.00);
                        pstmt11.setObject(8, "Stock Count");
                        pstmt11.setObject(9, null);
                        pstmt11.setDate(10, com.afrisoftech.lib.SQLDateFormat.getSQLDate(datePicker1.getDate()));
                        pstmt11.setString(11, user);
                        pstmt11.setObject(12, jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1));
                        pstmt11.setString(13, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        pstmt11.setObject(14, "Stock Count");
                        pstmt11.executeUpdate();

                    //  java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt31 = connectDB.prepareStatement("UPDATE st_stock_prices set balance = balance + "+new java.lang.Double(quantity)+" where department = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' and product = '"+jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).toString()+"'");
                        //  pstmt31.executeUpdate();
                    }
                }

                connectDB.commit();
                connectDB.setAutoCommit(true);

                jLabel12.setForeground(java.awt.Color.blue);
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data saved successfuly", "Information message!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                this.jButton1.setEnabled(false);
                jTextField1.setText("-");
                jTextField2.setText("-");
                // javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Enter quantity issued","Error Message!",javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                for (int k = 0; k < jTable1.getRowCount(); k++) {
                    for (int r = 0; r < jTable1.getColumnCount(); r++) {
                        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(null, k, r);
                    }
                }

                this.jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(null);
            } catch (java.sql.SQLException sq) {
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, sq.getMessage(), "Error Message!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                try {
                    connectDB.rollback();
                } catch (java.sql.SQLException sql) {
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, sql.getMessage(), "Error Message!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

        } catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "TRANSACTION ERROR : Please double check your entries.", "Error", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no way we can provide a solution without seeing the code, but I think that a probable cause would be users thinking that the application is non responsive and hitting the submit button again.

Comment: You should post some code if you want some help. Your issue could be frontend (like npinti pointed out) or backend.

Comment: What does the logs say? Is the logic to insert data is getting executed many times? If yes, then you need to figure out why? Can be a user issue or some quirk in the code.

Comment: I have investigated the possibility of users doing repeated entries while holding onto the button (like npinti suggests) but I realized that is not necessarily the case. I thought about network latency but still can't get where the problem is. let me post some code snippet from one of the forms.

Comment: Is there a possibility of the for loop executing more number of times than intended? It will be easy for you to fix if you can reproduce the issue in your local code base and put a debug point in your insert statement and where where the flow is coming from. In a glance code looks fine to me.

Comment: No databases repeats statements "on its own". This is **always** triggered by the application that connects to the database. My guess is that your code is simply executed multiple times - probably because of multiple clicks by the user or a "wrong" loop in your application. From where is that piece of code being called? If it's from within a Listener callback then maybe the event is sent multiple times. I usually write the equivalent of  `Thread.dumpStack();` into the logfile and then I can trace the callers of the function.